# SOQL: How to query parent object column in child object? Salsforce - Apex Class

Tags: apex, soql

I need Help
Here I have SOQL query:

```
final List<Attachment> attachments = [Select t.Id, t.Name, t.CreatedById, t.LastModifiedDate 
                                      From Attachment t 
                                      Where t.ParentId IN (Select t1.Id 
                                                           From Document__c t1 
                                                           Where t1.Opportunity__c = :this.id) 
                                      ORDER BY t.LastModifiedDate DESC];
```

I would Like query the LastModifiedDate of Documents not LastModifiedDate of Attachment.
I need to do something like this:

```
final List<Attachment> attachments = [Select t.Id, (select Id, LastModifiedDate 
                                      From Document__c 
                                      Where Opportunity__c =:this.id), t.Name, t.CreatedById 
                                      From Attachment t 
                                      Where t.ParentId IN (Select t1.Id 
                                                           From Document__c t1 
                                                           Where t1.Opportunity__c = :this.id) 
                                      ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC];
```

Regards,
Gari